# Exception error while deploying Jar files to weblogic 12.1.3

Tags: java, weblogic

Does anyone knows what causes such an exception ?

This is the error log:

```
<May 23, 2016 4:09:12 PM EDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "23430718618219" for task "3". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sdars.gui.business.ejb.UserBean_14f2ow_IUserImpl.<init>(weblogic.ejb.container.internal.StatelessLocalObject)"
    weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sdars.gui.business.ejb.UserBean_14f2ow_IUserImpl.<init>(weblogic.ejb.container.internal.StatelessLocalObject)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:175)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:170)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sdars.gui.business.ejb.XmUserBean_14f2ow_IXmUserImpl.<init>(weblogic.ejb.container.internal.StatelessLocalObject)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.StatelessEJBLocalHomeImpl.allocateBI(StatelessEJBLocalHomeImpl.java:71)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.StatelessEJBLocalHomeImpl.prepare(StatelessEJBLocalHomeImpl.java:44)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.SessionBeanInfoImpl.prepare(SessionBeanInfoImpl.java:462)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: `NoSuchMethodException` is usually caused by a version incompatibility between the libraries used to compile vs the libraries in the deployment environment.  When the code was compiled the method existed, but in the deployment environment the method does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Your ejb com.sdars.gui.business.ejb.XmUserBean does not declare a default constructor as requested by ejb specifications. That's why the EJB container (WebLogic) throws this exception. Correct the code of your ejb to add a default constructor (without arguments)